# Dynamically create a new object(s) from JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

From a service call, I receive similar JSON data like follows:

```
myArray: any = [
{item: 'Jelly Beans', areaCode: 321, Company: "Bob's Candy"},
{item: 'Skittles', areaCode: 444, Company: "Jim's Candy"},
{item: 'Snickers', areaCode: 321, Company: "Bob's Candy"},
{item: 'M&Ms', areaCode: 444, Company: "Jim's Candy"},
{item: 'Gummy Bears', areaCode: 123, Company: "Sally's Candy"}];
```

I need to split this into multiple arrays of objects dynamically, based on areaCode.

Or create a new object dynamically based on areaCode.

```
this.myArray= this.data.map(item => item.areaCode)
.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

I have thoughts of using the map function and filtering it out based on the areaCode, and then perhaps creating a new object with arrays based on areaCode. I just cannot seem to wrap my head around the process. If anyone could offer some advice I would be grateful.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are expecting something like this as output

```
{
"123":[{"item":"Gummy Bears","areaCode":123,"Company":"Sally's Candy"}],
  "321":[{"item":"Jelly Beans","areaCode":321,"Company":"Bob's Candy"}, 
         {"item":"Snickers","areaCode":321,"Company":"Bob's Candy"}],
  "444":[{"item":"Skittles","areaCode":444,"Company":"Jim's Candy"}, 
         {"item":"M&Ms","areaCode":444,"Company":"Jim's Candy"}]
}
```

then you can reduce to achieve it

```
const output = myArray.reduce((res,v) => {
    if(!res[v.areaCode]) {
        res[v.areaCode] = [v] 
    } else {
    res[v.areaCode].push(v)
    }
return res
},{} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use `.reduce` to convert your array to an object, and then use `Object.values()` to get your array of unique objects from the reduces object like so:

```js
const arr = [
{item: 'Jelly Beans', areaCode: 321, Company: "Bob's Candy"},
{item: 'Skittles', areaCode: 444, Company: "Jim's Candy"},
{item: 'Snickers', areaCode: 321, Company: "Bob's Candy"},
{item: 'M&Ms', areaCode: 444, Company: "Jim's Candy"},
{item: 'Gummy Bears', areaCode: 123, Company: "Sally's Candy"}];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {item, areaCode, Company}) => {
  if(areaCode in acc) {
    acc[areaCode].item.push(item);
  } else {
    acc[areaCode] = {item: [item], areaCode, Company};
  };
  
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```